# ASIHTTPRequest Request Cancel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, asihttprequest

I have been using ASIHTTPRequest to fetch the data and i want to cancel the request how i do it??
i do the code just like this..

```
-(void) serachData{
   NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:self.safestring];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:7200];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

 - (NSMutableDictionary *)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
 {
   NSLog(@"requestFinished");
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects[jsonobjectWithString:responseString], nil];
     NSLog(@"array %@",array);
  }

  - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
 NSLog(@"requestFailed");
 }
```

//if i press cancel button(when requestFinished /requestFailed method in  process ) then the ASIHTTPRequest fail and  finish method Stop /abort! how i do this??

```
 -(IBAction)CancleREquest:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"CancleREquest");
   }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your **cancel specific ASIHTTPRequest** then :

```
if(![yourASIHTTPRequest isCancelled]) 
{
    // Cancels an asynchronous request
    [yourASIHTTPRequest cancel];
    // Cancels an asynchronous request, clearing all delegates and blocks first
    [yourASIHTTPRequest clearDelegatesAndCancel];
}
```

Note : To **cancel all** **ASIHTTPRequest** then :

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *request in ASIHTTPRequest.sharedQueue.operations)
{
  if(![request isCancelled]) 
  {
     [request cancel];
     [request setDelegate:nil];
  }
}
```

**EDIT** : Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) as `ASIHTTPRequest` is deprecated as its has not been update since march 2011.

Comment: Add `for (ASIHTTPRequest *request in ASIHTTPRequest.sharedQueue.operations)` to get the `request` variable out.

Answer (score 6):

Nice simple version:

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *request in ASIHTTPRequest.sharedQueue.operations){
    [request cancel];
    [request setDelegate:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to keep a reference to the pending request in an ivar/property of your controller, then send the `cancel` message to it from your button handler.

```
//-- in your  class interface:
@property (nonatomic, assign) ASIFormDataRequest *request;

....

//-- in your  class implementation:
@synthesize request;

.....

-(void) serachData{
   NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:self.safestring];
   self.request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [self.request setTimeOutSeconds:7200];
   [self.request setDelegate:self];
   [self.request startAsynchronous];
}

-(IBAction)CancleREquest:(id)sender{
   [self.request cancel];
   NSLog(@"request Canceled");
}
```

You have several options when canceling, though; from [ASIHTTPRequest docs](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use):

> Cancelling an asynchronous request
>
> To cancel an asynchronous request (either a request that was started with [request startAsynchronous] or a request running in a queue you created), call [request cancel]. Note that you cannot cancel a synchronous request.
>
> Note that when you cancel a request, the request will treat that as an error, and will call your delegate and/or queue’s failure delegate method. If you do not want this behaviour, set your delegate to nil before calling cancel, or use the clearDelegatesAndCancel method instead.
>
> ```
>             // Cancels an asynchronous request
>             [request cancel]
>
>             // Cancels an asynchronous request, clearing all delegates and blocks first
>             [request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
> ```